# Cannot instantiate any F# type provider from FSharp.Data

Tags: f#, type-providers

I'm attempting to recreate the simplest example possible for the CSV type provider:

- I create a Library project in Visual Studio 2015, by default this
  targets F#4.0 and .NET 4.5.2.
- I add FSharp.Data 2.2.5 via NuGet.

Already, I have one error and one warning in my project:

> The type provider 'ProviderImplementation.JsonProvider' reported an
>   error: The type provider constructor has thrown an exception: API
>   restriction: The assembly 'file:///c:\users\james
>   foye\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\CsvExample\packages\FSharp.Data.2.2.5\lib\net40\FSharp.Data.dll'
>   has already loaded from a different location. It cannot be loaded from
>   a new location within the same appdomain. CsvExample  c:\users\james
>   foye\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\CsvExample\CsvExample\Library1.fs   1

and

> Referenced assembly 'c:\users\james foye\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\CsvExample\packages\FSharp.Data.2.2.5\lib\net40\FSharp.Data.dll'
>   has assembly level attribute
>   'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.TypeProviderAssemblyAttribute'
>   but no public type provider classes were
>   found CsvExample  c:\users\james foye\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\CsvExample\CsvExample\Library1.fs   1

All attempts to instantiate the provider fail, for example:

open FSharp.Data;;

let yahoo = CsvProvider<"sample.csv">;;

> C:\Data\Ebooks\F#\Deep Dives\Source\Chap6\YahooProvider\stdin(4,13):
>   error FS0039: The value or constructor 'CsvProvider' is not defined

It doesn't matter what I do to play around with the path (provide full path, change working directory of FSI, etc.)

Comment: My guess (since I was having this problem the other day) that the compiled project have different versions of F#.data

Comment: For the first error, try restarting visual studio

Comment: Indeed, restarting VS makes those errors go away.

Comment: And now I see that "let = " is wrong, it should be "type = ". Now it's working.

Comment: I suggest you write up the steps you took to make it work, post that as an answer to your own question, then accept your answer. (I think there's a two-day waiting period before you're allowed to accept your own answer). That would make it easier for people coming across this question later to find out what worked for you.

Comment: After skimming [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/10323), I solved a similar issue by updating to FSharp.Data 6.0.2. I don't know whether it's a fix or a workaround, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to get to the bottom of the compiler error, it almost seems like a bug somewhere with Visual Studio, NuGet, or some other part of the tool chain. But as mpeac suggested, simply restarting VS cleared it.

Once I did that I needed to change my code from declaring a let binding to defining a type. I had just mistakenly typed "let =" instead of "type =".

Comment: Same here! I had used `let .. = ` ' instead of `type .. =`