# CsvProvider type not defined

Tags: f#, f#-data

I'm attempting to use CsvProvider for f# but it says the type isn't defined even though I'm importing FSharp.Data.

```
open FSharp.Data

type test = CsvProvider<"C:\\First_Names.csv">
```

I'm not using the interactive scripts. This is an .fs file. It doesn't tell me that FSharp.Data  can't be found. It was even in the intellisense.

What are some ways I can diagnose this problem, because I'm at a loss now.

Comment: Have you added the reference correctly?

Comment: It may assist our psychic debugging powers if you also post the actual error message ;)

Comment: I just had to pull down FSharp.Data from nuget. I'm not sure why it didn't throw an Error, it may have to do with Isaac Abraham's answer.

Comment: I got the same error message, and I fiddled with my nuget packages and FSharp dependencies, without success. I was stuck, until I stumbled on the real problem. I had used `let .. = ` ' instead of `type .. =`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34487187/cannot-instantiate-any-f-type-provider-from-fsharp-data?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably due to the fact that you either having FSharp.Data.SqlClient referenced or FSharp.Data.TypeProviders (from the F#3 distribution). Both use that namespace hierarchy.

This is the same as how namespaces work in C# or VB .NET.

Comment: I pulled down the nuget package of FSharp.Data and then CsvProvider was found. You are saying there's a default FSharp.Data from the F#3 distribution that's out of date?

Comment: There is a different package - FSharp.Data.TypeProviders - which again has that namespace. It's a completely different package to FSharp.Data.

Comment: If you've got a reference to the proper FSharp.Data package - are you working in a script or a full-blown .fs file? If the latter - it should work out of the box. If the former - you'll need to #r to the DLL.

Comment: I had a fullblown .fs file. This is all kind of fuzzy to me. I still don't understand why it wouldn't work. I guess the namespace I was using before was out of date? I don't know. It's working now though and I'm facing new "opportunities for solution".

Comment: @IsaacAbraham I have the same error and Intellisense even works as well. I don't have FSharp.Data.SqlClient or FSharp.Data.TypeProviders referenced though. Is there anything else that could be causing this?